# Converting oracle dump (.dmp) files to sql file (PostgreSQL files)

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, database-backups

I would like to know the option of converting oracle dump to sql file (for PostgreSQL database). Is it possible to get the DDL, DML, and the data as well in the SQL file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an Oracle to PostgreSQL migration software.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago I wrote a little program explode  to convert the classical dmp file to csv files for easy loading. However, this is not the way to go since those file formats are undocumented.

A much smarter route to get the table definitions and data from oracle to Postgres is to use the oracle foreign data wrapper in postgres.

This allows for native -Postgres- access on the oracle tables but in a smarter way than the oracle database links. Check the docs and see if it fits your use case. If so, it will take out a lot of the conversion work for you.